# How to create a reload button when the connection is too slow in android

Tags: android, json, android-listview, progressdialog

Hey guys i am building an android application and it loads data from database using json. it loads ok when the internet is fast(3g or 4g or wifi) but when people are on 2g it gets very long to load the app crashes. How to catch that exception and create a retry button like the playstore does after you wait a long time??

My code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isAvailable();
        if (!network_connected) {
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        } else {
            accessWebService();
            registerCallClickBack();
        }
    }
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle(R.string.waiting);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_stocks));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            ListDrwaer();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[] { url });
    }
```

i checked the network connectivity to know if its connected or not but when it does a long time to connect it crashes how can i fix that??for example i want it to wait 10-15 secs and then a retry button to show up so the user retries.

Any help will be higly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a timer like 5000 ms and see if this timer is passed return null in your doInBackgroundFunction also initialize a flag like `reload =  false;`. If the timer has end `reload = true;`
In your onPostExecute check

```
if(reload)
{new JsonReadTask().execute(); }
```

edit here

```
  @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
boolean reload =false;
long waitTime = 5000;// or whatever you want the timeout length to be long 
curWaitTime = 0;
while (!reload && curWaitTime < waitTime)
 HttpResponse response;
 { // put your network

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
//test if jsonResult have the correct data if yes reload=true;
            }

            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 curWaitTime += 100; 
}
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 ListDrwaer();
            pDialog.dismiss();
if(!reload){
accessWebService();
}

        }

    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        // passes values for the urls string array
        task.execute(new String[] { url });
    }
```

Comment: how to create the timer?? can u be more specific??

Comment: yes on your doInBackground function put something like           long waitTime = 5000;  // or whatever you want the timeout length to be
long curWaitTime = 0;
while (!reload && curWaitTime < waitTime)
{
    // put your network/file code here
    // if the data finishes then you can set reload to true
    curWaitTime += 100; // or some other value to add
  
}
return null;                                                         if on your post execute function the reload is false call again the asynkTask

Comment: i still cannot fix it..can u help me with the code??i am noob sorry.